# An exception occurred processing JSP page /WEB-INF/views/ViewPage.jsp at line 130

Tags: java, spring, jsp

In Servlet.xml

```
<bean id="messageSource" class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource">
    <property name="basename" value="messages"/>
    <property name="defaultEncoding" value="UTF-8" />
</bean>
```

In messages.properties file in src/resources/messages.properties file

```
label.employeeId=Emp.ID
label.employeeName=Employee Name
label.dateOfBirth=DOB
label.annualIncome=Annual Income
label.bloodGroup=Blood group
label.qualification=Qualification
label.sex=Sex
label.phoneNumber=Phone No.
label.email=Email
label.edit=Edit
label.delete=Delete
```

jsp file code snippets and tags.

```
    <%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
    <%@taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags" prefix="spring" %>
    <%@ taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form" %>
    <%@ taglib prefix="spring" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags"%>
    <%@ page session="false" %>

    <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">

      <tr>  
        <td width="5%"><label for="Emp.ID"><spring:message code="label.employeeId"/></label></td>
        <td width="22%"><label for="Employee Name"><spring:message code="label.employeeName"/></label></td>
        <td width="6%"><label for="DOB"><spring:message code="label.dateOfBirth"/></label></td>
        <td width="7%"><label for="Annual Income"> <spring:message code="label.annualIncome"/></label> </td>
        <td width="9%"><label for="Blood group"> <spring:message code="label.bloodGroup"/></label> </td>
        <td width="11%"><label for="Qualification"> <spring:message code="label.qualification"/></label></td>
        <td width="7%"><label for="Sex"> <spring:message code="label.sex"/></label></td>
        <td width="10%"><label for="Phone No."> <spring:message code="label.phoneNumber"/></label></td>
        <td width="9%"><label for="Email"> <spring:message code="label.email"/></label></td>
        <td width="7%"><label for="Edit"> <spring:message code="label.edit"/></label></td>
        <td width="7%"><label for="Delete"> <spring:message code="label.delete"/></label></td>

      </tr>
```

When I run this program i'm getting errors like below

```
     Exception report
     message An exception occurred processing JSP page /WEB-INF/views/ViewPage.jsp at line 130
      description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.
Exception
        org.apache.jasper.JasperException: An exception occurred processing JSP page /WEB-INF/views/ViewPage.jsp at line 130
    127: <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
    128: 
    129:   <tr>  
    130:     <td width="5%"><label for="Emp.ID"><spring:message code="label.employeeId"/></label></td>
    131:     <td width="22%"><label for="Employee Name"><spring:message code="label.employeeName"/></label></td>
    132:     <td width="6%"><label for="DOB"><spring:message code="label.dateOfBirth"/></label></td>
    133:     <td width="7%"><label for="Annual Income"> <spring:message code="label.annualIncome"/></label> </td>
```

Stacktrace:

```
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.handleJspException(JspServletWrapper.java:568)
            org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:455)
            org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:395)
            org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:339)
            javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
            org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
            org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceView.renderMergedOutputModel(InternalResourceView.java:238)
            org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:262)
            org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1180)
            org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:950)
            org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:852)
            org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:882)
            org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:778)
            javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:620)
            javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
            org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
        root cause

        javax.servlet.ServletException: javax.servlet.jsp.JspTagException: No message found under code 'label.employeeId' for locale 'en_US'.
            org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.doHandlePageException(PageContextImpl.java:916)
            org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.handlePageException(PageContextImpl.java:845)
            org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.views.ViewPage_jsp._jspService(ViewPage_jsp.java:264)
            org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
            javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
            org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:432)
            org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:395)
            org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:339)
            javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
            org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
            org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceView.renderMergedOutputModel(InternalResourceView.java:238)
            org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:262)
            org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1180)
            org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:950)
            org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:852)
            org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:882)
            org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:778)
            javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:620)
            javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
            org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
        root cause

        javax.servlet.jsp.JspTagException: No message found under code 'label.employeeId' for locale 'en_US'.
            org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.MessageTag.doStartTagInternal(MessageTag.java:184)
            org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.RequestContextAwareTag.doStartTag(RequestContextAwareTag.java:79)
            org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.views.ViewPage_jsp._jspx_meth_spring_005fmessage_005f0(ViewPage_jsp.java:420)
            org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.views.ViewPage_jsp._jspService(ViewPage_jsp.java:195)
            org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
            javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
            org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:432)
            org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:395)
            org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:339)
            javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
            org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
            org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceView.renderMergedOutputModel(InternalResourceView.java:238)
            org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:262)
            org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1180)
            org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:950)
            org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:852)
            org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:882)
            org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:778)
            javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:620)
            javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
            org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
```

When run my program i'm getting above errors I had posted my properties file ,jsp file and servlet.xml file please help me to fix this error. I had placed my `messages.properties` file in `src/resource`s folder/ messages.properties file

Comment: Assuming you are using maven or the likes the file should be in `src/main/resources`. Also the `basename` should probably be `classpath:messages` instead of just `messages`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **root cause** of the exception is clear:

```
javax.servlet.jsp.JspTagException: No message found under code 'label.employeeId' for locale 'en_US'.
```

In your properties files, you are missing the property `label.employeeId`. Please add it in your `messages.properties` properties file.

Correction: seeing that you have already the `label.employeeId` in your properties file, your location of the file might be in the wrong place. Perhaps it should be located in `src/main/resources/` directory (if your project is Mavenized).

Comment: I'm not using maven  i'm using Spring mvc please help me how to fix it ...In Spring MVC

Comment: Then what is the project structure of your project?